# problemas al usar system("pause");

Tags: visual-c++

Estoy programando en *Visual Studio* para una tarea en **C++** mi problema es que al usar los comandos `system("pause");`, `system("clear");` y `system("cls");` me los detecta como virus.

El error que me devuelve:

> El término '.\tarea11.exe' no se reconoce como nombre de un cmdlet, función, archivo de script o programa ejecutable. Compruebe si escribió correctamente el nombre o, si incluyó una ruta de acceso, compruebe que
> dicha ruta es correcta e inténtelo de nuevo.
> En línea: 1 Carácter: 3
>
> - & .'tarea11.exe'
> - CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (.\tarea11.exe:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
> - FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException

Comment: Puedes desactivar el antivirus o buscar otra opción. Para pausar puedes utilizar `cin.get()` e imprimir el mensaje con `cout`. Para limpiar la consola, lo más simple es llenar la pantalla de espacio en blanco. O puedes averiguar cómo de hace en cada sistema operativo. La documentación de Windows muestra 3 maneras (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/clearing-the-screen).